# Don't show #N/A in Excel cell but also don't treat it as a 0 value in a chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I have a column whose content is conditioned upon another column:

```
=IF(B8<>"";B8/($J$2 * $J$2);"")
```

This column is the line data for a chart. It works fine when the `IF` condition is met. However, any `ELSE` `""` value is considered as `0` in the chart and the line crashes down to the bottom.

The alternative is to use

```
=IF(B8<>"";B8/($J$2 * $J$2);NA())
```

But then it looks ugly in the spreadsheet with loads of `#N/A` in the column.

Any solution aside from putting a conditional formatting on top which makes the font color white when the value is `#N/A`?

Comment: try this formula `=IF(AND(B8<>"",$J$2 <>0),B8/($J$2 * $J$2),"")`

Comment: @MoKhalefa It's not the `IF` condition that's causing the problem but rather the resulting `""` for the else case which then causes trouble in a chart. I clarified the question for this part.

Comment: you mean that `""` or `0` are not allowed Right?

Comment: I think your proposed conditional formatting is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot with a Named Range which will evaluate `0` to `#NA`

If the data you're plotting is in `C3:C8`:

1. Create a Name for that Range which evaluates `0` as `#NA` (I've called the Range "PLOT", but you can give it any name you want): `=IF(Sheet1!$C$3:$C$8=0,NA(),Sheet1!$C$3:$C$8)`
2. Use the Named range in the Chart: `=SERIES(,,Book1!PLOT,1)`

This will allow you to keep the `ELSE`-cells as `""` in your sheet, whilst still showing up as `#NA` to the Chart and hence not collapsing the line to zero

NB: See [here](https://peltiertech.com/chart-series-formula/) for notes on how to use Named Ranges in charts, particularly:

*If your references are Names (Named Ranges), you need to qualify the Name with the scope of the Name, that is, either its parent worksheet or the parent workbook.*

*=SERIES(Sheet1!TheSeriesName,Sheet1!TheXValues,Sheet1!TheYValues,1)*

*You can enter the Name qualified by the worksheet, and if the Name is scoped to the workbook, Excel will fix it for you.*

Comment: Thanks that worked! It took me a bit longer because I made the classic copy&paste mistake and for some weird reason MS decided to translate function names into each locality. So `NA()` produced an error because it should have been `NV()` in my local version of Excel.
Thanks for your help! :-)